# Possible bug: Quantity[2,"meters"] returns 2 None meters

Tags: bugs, units

**Bug introduced in version 10 or earlier and fixed in version 10.0.2**

---

I'm using 10.0 for Linux.

Trial 1:

```
Quantity[2,"meters"]
2 None meters
```

Trial 2:

```
Quantity[2,"Meters"]
2 meters
```

Trial 3:

```
Quantity[2,"meters"] //InputForm
Quantity[2*None, "Meters"]
```

It seems like MMA recognizes the correct unit, but also is sticking a None in some cases. I first happened upon this possible-bug by using "ElectronVolts" rather than "Electronvolts".

Is this a bug? (Should it be reported?)

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug to me ... though I don't use units, so I don't have much experience with this.  I would report it.

Comment: Yes, this does look like bad behavior due to an update on the Wolfram|Alpha server.  I've notified the developers responsible for this content.

Comment: @NickLariviere Thank you.

Comment: it probably is worth noting that it might be a good idea to use the "canonical unit names" in everything that you intend to run more than once. Doing so should (I think) not show the mentioned problem and also will be much faster and work without an internet connection, which alone seems to justify the effort to find out what these "canoncial unit names" are. To do that, just look at the `InputForm` of what a `Quantity` is transformed to. Getting the interpretation of unit strings from the Wolfram|Alpha servers is a design decisions which is certainly arguable...

Comment: @JacobSchwartz, sorry for the delay in getting back but this should be resolved now(if you're still having trouble please let me know).

Comment: @NickLariviere works! Thanks again.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed --- the examples work correctly for me.  (10.0.2 Mac.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug. It has been fixed as of 10.0.2.

```
In[1]:= Quantity[2, "meters"]
Out[1]= 2 m
```